# Compare two git branches without intermediate commits (i.e. only commits that are accessible from the branches)

Tags: git, compare, branch, diff

Let's assume i have a git master branch and two feature branches on the same commit (feature1, feature2):

```
A1 -- A2 (master)
       \
        B1 -- B2 (feature1, feature2)
```

Now i rebase feature2 branch with changes from master:

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 -- A4 -- A5 -- A6 (master)
       \                        \
        B1 -- B2 (feature1)      B1 -- B2 (feature2)
```

And do perhaps some refactorings (`B2'`) and additional changes (`B3`) on feature2:

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 -- A4 -- A5 -- A6 (master)
       \                        \
        B1 -- B2 (feature1)      B1 -- B2' -- B3 (feature2)
```

What i want to do is get the diff from only the contents of the two feature branches (and not the master branch) in order to see what was refactored and changed on the feature branch, not on master. I.e. i want to get the diff between `B1 -- B2` and `B1 -- B2' -- B3`. I don't care for the changes that were pushed to master in the meantime. Is there a cmd command for that?

Comment: Try `git log feature1..feature2` and `git log feature2..feature1`

Comment: As explained here: https://devconnected.com/how-to-compare-two-git-branches/ this will also use master commits (In short, it will show you ALL the commits that “branch2” has that are not in “branch1”.)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the `git diff` command only compares explicit contents, there is no built-in way to combine several patches together.

What you can do is create a temporary branch, and create the content you wish to compare :

```
# for example :
git checkout feature1
git checkout -b compare1
git rebase A6
git diff feature2
```

---

An alternate way to build that content could be to apply patch `A2 A6` on top of `feature1`, or the reverse patch on top of `feature2` :

```
git checkout feature1
git diff A2 A6 | git apply

# or
git checkout feature2
git diff A6 A2 | git apply

# after inspecting the diff : discard these changes
git checkout .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to work, but i'm wondering whether there is some way without creating temporary branch...

Comment: @user2248673: not really, no. You don't need to create a *named* branch, but you need to create a new commit or prototype-ready-to-be-commited (in your work-tree or in Git's index) and it's easy to see why you can view this as a "temporary branch", even if you didn't make a commit from it. So in a technical sense, yes: you definitely don't need a *name*. But you have to assemble the files somehow.